# How can I get a windows users session id using C#?

Tags: c#, windows

I would like to get the windows session ID of a specific logged in user.  How can this be done in C#?

Comment: This is a poorly thought out question.  It has traveled far down the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858) except you've noted the end result.  The title should just be the end result, and you should mention that in order to logoff a user you've found information regarding the session ID.  Do you just want to log off the current user session your application is running in?

Comment: WTSEnumerateSessionsEx() + WTSDisconnectSession().  I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after doing some digging, I found the [Cassia](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/) library.  Getting the session id for a specific user is easy:

```
ITerminalServicesManager manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
        using (ITerminalServer server = manager.GetLocalServer())
        {
            server.Open();
            var result = server.GetSessions().Where(x => x.UserName == "name").SingleOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine(result.SessionId);
        }
```

Comment: after a lot of search,this is what i want,tanx @broke